Vuetify v-data-table search/sort nested object when used for items prop
I have a v-data-table that fills nicely from a axios request and is bound to an interface. I also use this same interface for updating my API so I would prefer to keep my data in this form. However, I am struggling to get the search and sorting functionality to filter down the table. Typically I would flatten the table to make the search work but I was hoping there was a way to do this without flattening my data array and staying consistent with my interfaces:
<template>
  <v-container>
      <v-row class="justify-space-between pb-10">
        <div class="d-flex align-center">
          <h1 class="text-h4 pb-none mx-5">Rate Review Management</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-flex align-center">
          <div class="d-none d-md-flex mx-2" style="width:300px">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="search"
                append-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Dynamic Search"
                density="compact"
                variant="outlined"
                clearable
                rounded
                hide-details
                single-line
                flat
                color="primaryDarken4"/>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="data" :search="search">
          <template v-slot:[`item.review`]="{ item }">
            <v-autocomplete
              label="ReviewAnalyst"
              v-model="item.review_analyst.internal_user_number"
              :items="reviewAnalystsData"
              item-value="internal_user_number"
              :item-title="item=>`${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`"
              variant="outlined"
              rounded
              hide-details
              class="my-5"
              density="compact"
              @blur="updateStateAssigments(item)"
            />
          </template>
          <template v-slot:[`item.backup_analyst`]="{ item }">
            <v-autocomplete
              label="Backup Analyst"
              v-model="item.backup_analyst.internal_user_number"
              :items="reviewAnalystsData"
              item-value="internal_user_number"
              :item-title="item=>`${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`"
              variant="outlined"
              rounded
              hide-details
              class="my-5"
              density="compact"
              @blur="updateStateAssigments(item)"
            />
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import {ref, watch, computed} from 'vue'
  import { useCertificationReviewStore } from '../store/certification-review-store'
  import { StateAssignments, User } from '@/interfaces/interfaces';

  //load stores
  const certificationReviewStore = useCertificationReviewStore()

  const headers = ref<any>([
    { title: 'State', key: 'entity_name', align: 'start'},
    { title: 'Primary Reviewer', key: 'review_analyst', align: 'start'},
    { title: 'Backup Reviewer', key: 'backup_analyst', align: 'start'}])

  const data = ref<StateAssignments[]>()
  const search = ref<string>('')
  const reviewAnalystsData = ref<User[]>([])

  const getAssignments = async () => {
    data.value = await certificationReviewStore.getAssignments()
  }
  const getReviewAnalystData = async () => {
    reviewAnalystsData.value = await certificationReviewStore.getReviewAnalysts()
  }

  const updateStateAssigments = (stateAssignment : StateAssignments) => {
    certificationReviewStore.updateStateAssignments(stateAssignment)
  }

  const loadInitialData = async () => {
    await Promise.all([getAssignments(), getReviewAnalystData()])
  }

  loadInitialData()

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>

